# How can I validate that I am passing an Asset into my custom twig filter?

Tags: twigextension

I'm creating a custom twig filter in Craft 3 and am struggling with a really simple thing.

```
{{ entry.backgroundImage.one() | filter }}
```

In my filter, I would like to validate that I am being passed an asset.

```
if (!$asset instanceof Asset)
{
    return false;
}
```

What should I be checking the object against? Asset or something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you had your code just right imo:

```
use craft\elements\Asset;
```

...

```
if (!$asset instanceof Asset) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: looks like I forgot `use craft\elements\Asset;` which would have made the original code work. Thanks!

Comment: I think doing it this way is a good bit cleaner

Comment: I actually agree that this is probably the cleaner solution. In comparing `get_class` and `instanceof`, a useful detail to know is that `instanceof` will also return `true` for a class _extending_ the class you're testing against (i.e. your conditional will evaluate to `true` if you pass it an object w/ a class _extending_ Asset, which may or may not be what you want), where `get_class($object) === 'SomeClass'` will only evaluate to `true` if the object actually has that particular class. In this case, I'm fairly positive it doesn't matter and both approaches will work.

Comment: Also, instead of hard coding the full, namespaced classname, it's also possible to do `use craft\elements\Asset; ... if (\get_class($asset) === Asset::class) { ...` of course :)

Comment: That is a great callout @MatsMikkelRummelhoff, great to know that this will also acknowledge exertions. In light of this, I've mad this the correct answer.

Comment: `instanceof` is also a language construct, so it'll be a bit more performant (not that it really matters in most cases): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017684/what-is-the-difference-between-is-a-and-instanceof

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Craft 3, this should work:

```
if (\get_class($asset) !== 'craft\elements\Asset) {
    return false;
}
```